# Http.Get: arrays of string pairs - Type {string, string}[] is not assignable to type string[]

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, http-get

I have an API I'm writing that has an item that defines a relationship between two other item types. I want to be be able to get this item by the ids of the corresponding item types:

```
getItem(ids: {id1: string, id2: string}[]){ ... }
```

But when I call `http.get()`, it seems that `get()` only accepts strings and first order arrays of strings as parameters.

I know I can separate the `ids` array into two arrays: `ids1: string[], ids2: string[]`, but that seems sloppy to me, and seems to invite discrepancies between the sizes of the two arrays. Or I could throw the id pairs into JSON, but it seems that would lose type specification.

I would prefer to keep just one array if possible; is there any way to do so, or do I just have to suck it up and write it with two arrays?

Comment: Can't you have something like `ids1 = ids.map(id => id.id1); ids2 = ids.map(id => id.id2)` in your getItem function?

Comment: I gave up on this idea when I realized that my primary use case actually involved one of the ids being the same throughout, so I ended up making a preprocessing step on the API side that allows for arrays of different lengths, filling a single item array with that item to match the length of the other array if necessary, then using `Array.zip()` to construct the final tuple array that finally gets iterated over to lookup the return items. I'll still leave the question up in case anyone has an answer to it that someone else might need in the future.